# Cassandra : The maximum size of an item in a collection is 64K

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3, cqlsh, cassandra-cli

Is there is an alternate if collection data is more than 64K.

According to [cassandra doc](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html)

```
Observe the following limitations of collections:

The maximum size of an item in a collection is 64K.
Keep collections small to prevent delays during querying because Cassandra reads a collection in its entirety. The collection is not paged internally.

As discussed earlier, collections are designed to store only a small amount of data.
Never insert more than 64K items in a collection.

If you insert more than 64K items into a collection, only 64K of them will be queryable, resulting in data loss.
```

Comment: How much larger are you looking for? They seem to recommend keeping cell values to < 10MB.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would suggest you not to use the C* collections. Use the combination of **partition key** and **clustering columns** instead. So you don't have the 64K limit.

Link: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html

Comment: If user are have different groups. For eg the user1 having student, teacher, friend and so on .. where as user2 having student,  friend and colleagues. In this case student and friend is duplicated than how we maintain that ..

Comment: I think you have the same problem using C* collections too, but it's ok. You should not try to denormalize your data like in relational DBs.